# reactjs material ui custom component onchange error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created my own custom component in reactjs called `OutlinedFieldWithLabelAndPrefix`
to save values with prefix. Values like, `MYR-13245`

My problem is that this line `onChange={evt => prefix1Setter(evt.target.prefix1)}` gives error. The html browser throws error for that line.

```
    import {Paper, InputBase, Divider} from '@material-ui/core';
    const styles = theme => ({
        prefix: {
            marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            flex: 1
        }
    });



    const OutlinedFieldWithLabelAndPrefix = props => {
    const { classes, config } = props;
    const { prefix1, prefix1Setter, value, valueSetter, label, disabledThis = false } = config;

      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes.label}>
            {label}
          </div>
          <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <InputBase
              type="text"
              value={prefix1}
              onChange={evt => prefix1Setter(evt.target.prefix1)}
              className={classes.prefix}
              maxLength="3"
              inputProps={{
                root: classes.inputRoot
              }}
            />
            <div>-</div>
            <InputBase
          type="number"
          value={value}
          onChange={evt => valueSetter(evt.target.value)}
          maxLength="5"
          className={classes.input}
          inputProps={{
            root: classes.inputRoot
          }}
        />
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: and what's in config?

Comment: config is this line `const { prefix1, prefix1Setter, value, valueSetter, label, disabledThis = false } = config;`

Comment: error is, the ui loads perfectly, but when i type in a value into the box, `onChange={evt => prefix1Setter(evt.target.prefix1)}` throws , handle change eror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This onChange handler should be

```
onChange={evt => prefix1Setter(evt.target.prefix1)}
```

should be

```
onChange={evt => prefix1Setter(evt.target.value)}
```